# Simply remove a url segment with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am simply trying to get this URL:

```
http://foo.com/entry/random-entry-123
```

to redirect to:

```
http://foo.com/random-entry-123
```

The "random-entry-123" is dynamic.
 Different for each entry.
Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming no further rewrites are in use, and all links inside `/entry/` are to rewritten, then try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/entry/(.+)$ /$1 [L,QSA]
```

Lose the `[L]` if there are further rewrites ahead in the file.

Answer (score 3):

Although this has already been answered, it didn't work for me when I had two segments after the first, eg:

```
http://foo.com/entry/random-segment/random-entry-123
```

Instead this worked for me and also takes care of 301 redirects:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /entry/(.*) /$1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not following .. how does the `ar` portion of your `RedirectMatch` relate to the URL path you gave as an example?

Comment: It should be /entry/ not /ar/ - Sorry, I have edited.