# Joomla 2.5: How to remove the parent category from URLs?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm trying to migrate my Web site from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 2.5. After running RedMigrator I've got all articles imported in my new Web site. The URL of Joomla 2.5 articles is however different from the original one. In particular I'd like to get rid from the URL of the **parent** category so that it looks like
**host/category/article**
instead of:
**host/parent-category/category/article**
Is there any way to do it from the configuration or do I have to use mod_rewrite to get my URL rewrited by Apache ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience there's no way to do this without third-party extensions, though you might experiement with creating a hidden menu containing an item for the sub-category's blog layout.

[Simply remove a url segment with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823870/simply-remove-a-url-segment-with-htaccess)

In your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/parent-category/(.+)$ /$1 [L,QSA]
```