# Magento store code in URL only for one domain

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url, mod-rewrite, configuration

I have a magento setup with 2 domains, one of them having 3 languages. For this one I need the store view to be displayed in the url, however for the first one there should be no store code there.

Is it possible to configure Magento (or htaccess) so that the store code is not displayed for one of the domains?

*The problem is that for Magento CE 1.9 this setting is a global one.*

**Current URL status:**

domain 1: domain1.com/base

domain 2: domain2.com/en domain2.com/fr domain2.com/de

**Desired URL status:**

domain 1: domain1.com/ where the URL will be like this for a category domain1.com/catname

domain 2: domain2.com/en domain2.com/fr domain2.com/de

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed there isn't a setting for what you want.  You'll have to go through each store view and set the base URL to `http://domain2.com/en/`, `http://domain2.com/fr/` and so on.  Then set the JS/CSS/media URLs to `http://domain2.com/` so they still work.

Comment: Tried it. Seems perfectly logical however visiting any page iyelds a 404 error. The index for URL has been rebuilt

Comment: I see.  The `/en/` or `/fr/` is still in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` when Magento checks so it cannot understand the path.  Someone better at .htaccess rewrites might be able to solve that but I cannot.

Comment: If a browser visits `domain2.com/en/` we would normally expect it to be handled by `/var/www/en/index.php` (or wherever the local www folder is) but in fact is handled by `/var/www/index.php` and the path that Magento sees is `/en/` instead of `/`.  A clever rewrite rule could strip that store code out, I think it has something to do with a passthrough rule but never got it to work.

Comment: I found this earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823870/simply-remove-a-url-segment-with-htaccess and it looks to be solving the problem, but again I was hoping Magento could do the job by itself.