# How do I hide a directory in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory, subdirectory

Okay, say I have the website example.com

My website theme is located at
example.com/directory/themes/name/

And thus, the direct url to a picture, for example, is:
example.com/directory/themes/name/images/image.png

I would like to mask or rewrite the "directory" folder so in the url it's shown as:
example.com/themes/name/images/image.png

instead of
example.com/directory/themes/name/images/image.png

---

In other words simply making it so

example.com/directory/themes

example.com/directory/plugins

**are changed to:**

example.com/themes

example.com/plugins

Thank you!

Edit:

I have gotten the following to work in a way such that everything is accessible. The only problem is that example.com/directory/themes/...etc  doesn't redirect to example.com/themes/...etc

```
RewriteCond $1 !^directory
RewriteRule ^(.*) /directory/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The only thing I've found to "sort of" work is:
`RewriteRule ^themes.* /directory/$0 [L]

RewriteRule ^plugins.* /directory/$0 [L]`

The only problem is that when navigating to `example.com/directory/themes/name/images/image.jpg` for example, it doesn't redirect to `example.com/themes/name/images/image.jpg.`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no further rewrites are in use, and all links inside /directory/ are to rewritten, then try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/directory/(.+)$ /$1 [L,QSA]
```

Lose the [L] if there are further rewrites ahead in the file.

This answer was taken from [Simply remove a url segment with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823870/simply-remove-a-url-segment-with-htaccess)

And was already answered. Please search a bit more in the feature.

Comment: I have browsed dozens of posts with no solution. The answer you suggested does not work as is.