# Codeigniter use extra url parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess

In codeigniter I want to have one url segment to not be consider.

```
example.com/app/dev1/controller/function/id
example.com/app/dev2/controller/function/id
```

base url is

```
baseUrl = example.com/app
```

When I use this type of url, codeigniter consider "dev1" as controller, "controller" as function, so I get error of page not found.

I want to know if I can code which don't consider first parameter as controller and it start considering from second parameters.

I can not add in base url as it is not constant we can have en, fr, nl etc so do we have anything that help in this case I don't want to add query string "?".
Can we do anything using .htaccess

Comment: you should use as `example.com/app/controller/function/fr/id` because codeigniter manage languages also, so load language in controller constructor

Comment: it is parameter that I use to load some data not language.

Comment: you can use that param after function name as argument.

Comment: That is param I need before application get loaded in main index.php, in every url, so I can not add to every function as last param.

Comment: dev1 and dev2 are folders in the controller directory?

Comment: no, dev1 and dev2 are not folder, it is just parameter I need in url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we will neeed to create new file "MY_Router.php" in "/application/core" folder, with following content

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Router extends CI_Router {

 protected function _parse_routes()
 {
    // do logic you needed

    unset($this->uri->segments[1]);

    // Return default function
    return parent::_parse_routes();
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose url is like following : www.paintes.com/painters-in-chennai
then route can be like following

```
    $route['painters-in-(:any)'] ='index/paintersIn/$1';
```

in **index.php** controller, i'll be able to receive chennai like following

```
    function paintesIn($city_name)
    {
        echo $city_name //OUTPUT WILL BE "chennai"
    }
```

if url is like www.paintes.com/painters-in-mumbai , then output will be mumbai

as per your request, URL is liek following : www.paintes.com/mumbai-painters
then you can write like following

```
    $route['(:any)-painters'] ='index/paintersIn/$1';
```

Comment: I have 1000 of such folder and I want to remove that folder so I can manage it well that is why I want such structure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your CodeIgniter routes properly. Example:

```
$route['dev1/controller/fun/(:num)']  = "dev1/controller/fun/index/$1";
```

See https://blog.biernacki.ca/2011/12/codeigniter-uri-routing-issue-with-controller-folders/

Comment: I have that "dev1" part dynamic with more than 1000 value, so I can not write every single route for it.

Comment: also I have countless functions, I have to write for very function in routes which is also not manageable.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a URI Routing [regular expression](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#regular-expressions) like this to skip the `dev` part and go straight to the desired controller :

```php
$route['dev(:num)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/(\d+)'] = '$2/$3/$4'; // rule to match method with parameter
$route['dev(:num)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)'] = '$2/$3'; // rule to match method without parameter
```

Or if you don have a common `dev` URI segment, you could use `:any` rule :

```php
$route['(:any)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/(\d+)'] = '$2/$3/$4'; // rule to match method with parameter
$route['(:any)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)'] = '$2/$3'; // rule to match method without parameter
```

Comment: I don't have just "dev" as prefix I just gave it for example, I have many different name of it.

Comment: did it have a similarity in name, or all of it have completely different names? I write that rule since you are giving an example of `dev1` and `dev2` which have the same `dev` name

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go for the following in routing

```
$route['dev1/(:any)'] ='dev1/$1';
$route['dev1/(:any)/(:any)'] ='dev1/$1/$2';
$route['dev1/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] ='dev1/$1/$2/$3';
```

Its rare that `Codeigniter` treats folder name as controller, try renaming folderas well.

Otherwise above solution should work.

Comment: it is not treating folder as controller, it is extra parameter I need in every url,

Comment: I have thousands of dynamic such "dev1", I can not write route for all.

Comment: yes i get it, you want
`$route['(anyThingHere)/controller/method'] = 'controller/method/param';`
like this?

Comment: Yes, I want like that.

Comment: See if there is change you can do it with htaccess, pick first segment of URL and put it in last. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4823870/2107145 or rewrite to whatever you want.

Comment: Yes, I am asking for .htaccess, one you gave me is for constant parameter, I need some similar for dynamic.

Comment: Yes I get it, I am searching `.htaccess` which should pick `/dev1/controller/method`
and convert to `controller/method/dev1` for you if i could. should not be hard coded but just pick first segment and re-write in last.
Check this: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/102403/27413. try doing some workaround it.